# Nexus 7 won't boot after being powered down...unless plugged in

Tags: nexus-7

I have powered down my new Nexus on a couple of occasions now, but it will not boot up subsequently UNLESS it is plugged into the charger. Is this by design? I've also had it go into this unresponsive state after being charged overnight; in that case, I turned the charger off and on again and it was OK.

Anyone had this happen to them? Do I have a faulty unit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just double-checked mine, and it boots fine without the charger (battery at 64%).  I suspect your unit is faulty.

Comment: Thanks for checking for me, pgs. That's what I thought. I need to decide whether to take it back now, as it's fine apart from this one little issue.